# BCrypt.hashpw <when i use this class in netbeans >

Tags: java, bcrypt

How to declare this what is import methods we have for BCrypt class

Here my code is:

```
String inputCurrentPassword = null;
if(request.getParameter("inputCurrentPassword")!=null) {
    inputCurrentPassword = BCrypt.hashpw(request.getParameter("inputCurrentPassword"), GlobalConstants.SALT);   
};
```

Comment: Please, take a look at this link: https://github.com/jeremyh/jBCrypt. If you use Maven, the link provides you with what must be included on your pom.xml so the library will be included.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking - looks like you are using [jBcrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/). In any case you must not use a shared, global salt value. Use the `gensalt` function as show in the example.